# How to write tests using QuickCheck for the definition of ($)

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

And also for composing function.

```
f $ a = f a
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Comment: Do you really have to test those? I think their implementation is forced by their type (by their associated free theorem).

Comment: Actually this is an exercise from [haskellBook](http://haskellbook.com/)

Comment: I see, so it's an exercise just for the sake of it. I have no idea about what a meaningful test could be for those, though. I mean, I could compare test them against their own definitions, which feels weird.

Answer (score 0):

QuickCheck works only on concrete types, so you first need to instantiate the type:

```
($) :: (Int -> String) -> Int -> String
```